# How to add the same class for all the td using javaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I am new to js.
How to add the same class for all the td using javaScript

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>  
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="c0"></td>
      <td id="c1"></td>
      <td id="c2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="c3"></td>
      <td id="c4"></td>
      <td id="c5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="c6"></td>
      <td id="c7"></td>
      <td id="c8"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried it like this but i am getting this erorr
Uncaught TypeError: all.setAttribute is not a function
at script.js:9
js

```
const  all = document.querySelectorAll('td');
all.setAttribute('class', 'tds');
```

Comment: you need a loop. `all.forEach(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `querySelectorAll` here, So you will get array like elements of all HTML `td` element

You just have to loop over and add class to it

```
const all = document.querySelectorAll('td');
all.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.setAttribute('class', 'tds');
});
```

You can also use

```
item.classList.add("tds");
```

**Note: For demo purpose, I've used added text in between `td` and some CSS.**

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('td');
all.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.setAttribute('class', 'tds');
});
```

```css
.tds{
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="c0">c0</td>
    <td id="c1">c1</td>
    <td id="c2">c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c3">c3</td>
    <td id="c4">c4</td>
    <td id="c5">c5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c6">c6</td>
    <td id="c7">c7</td>
    <td id="c8">c8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy using jquery, it can work with a single line of code as seen below

```js
$("td").attr("class", "tds");
```

```css
/*To show that it works, i added a css code to change the background color so you know it really added the class to the td*/

.tds{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="c0">c0</td>
    <td id="c1">c1</td>
    <td id="c2">c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c3">c3</td>
    <td id="c4">c4</td>
    <td id="c5">c5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c6">c6</td>
    <td id="c7">c7</td>
    <td id="c8">c8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```